# R: passing column names as variables in custom function

Tags: r, function, variables, dataframe

I am quite new to R and programming in general and have been struggling with the following for a few hours now.

I am trying to create a function that will take a df and a column name as variables, filter the table based on the column name provided and print the output.

```
example_function <- function(df=df, col=col){
         a <- df[col == 100,]
         b <- filter(df, col == 100)
         print(a)
         print(b)
}
```

Using `example_function(df=example_df, col='percentage')` doesn't work, both variables return just the column names but no data rows (despite there being values == 100).

Using `example_function(df=df, col=percentage)`, so percentage isn't surrounded by quotes here, I get:

> Error in `[.data.frame`(df, col == 100, ) :    object 'percentage' not
>   found

However, when I run `example_function(df=example_df, col=example_df$percentage)` I get the correct result, with my dataframe returning as expected with only those rows where the `example_df$percentage` is equal to 100.

I really want to be able to pass the df as one variable and the column as another without having to type `example_df$percentage` each time as I want to be able to re-use the function for many different dataframes and typing that seems redundant.

Based on this I then modified the function thinking that I can just use `df$col` in the function and it will evaluate to `example_df$percentage` and work like it did above:

```
example_function <- function(df=df, col=col){
     a <- df[df$col == 100,]
     b <- filter(df, df$col == 100)
     print(a)
     print(b)
}
```

But now I get another error when using `example_function(df=example_df, col=percentage)` or when passing `col='percentage'`:

> Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : Result must have length 19, not 0

Would any body be able to help me fix this, or point me in the right direction to understand why what I'm doing isn't working?

Thanks so much

Here is an example of the dataframe I am using (although my real one will have more columns but I hope it won't make a difference for this example.)

```
 name    | percentage
    -----------------------
    tom      |  80
    john     |  100
    harry    |  99
    elizabeth|  100
    james    |  50




  example_df <- structure(list(name = structure(c(5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("elizabeth", 
    "harry", "james", "john", "tom"), class = "factor"), percentage = c(80L, 
    100L, 99L, 100L, 50L)), .Names = c("name", "percentage"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -5L))
```

- as a note, I have updated my col=names to col=percentage in this example to more accurately represent what I am doing. In my attempt to generalise the example I used col=names and now realise that it wasn't a very good example (as you quite rightly asserted that a 'name' is never likely to be numeric). The above problems still persist for me however.

** Update: I managed to get it working with the following:

```
example_function <- function(df=df, col=col){
     a <- df[df[col] == 100,]
     print(a)
}
```

passing `example_function(df=example_df, col='percentage')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first row of `example_function` should be

```
a <- df[df[[col]] == 100,]
```

When you break it down, `df[['names']] == 100` will give you a list of logicals corresponding to which rows of `df` has a `names` value of 100.  But `'names' == 100` is nonsensical:  it's always false.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I updated the function like you suggested but now I am getting a different error:  Error in (function(x, i, exact) if (is.matrix(i)) as.matrix(x)[[i]] else .subset2(x,  : 
  object 'names' not found

Comment: @0mm3 It's difficult to figure out why without sample data.  Can you edit your question to include a sample of what `df` looks like?